# Test elements rendered in Angular app with Jasmine tests?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

This should be a very simple question, I hope... I am an Angular newbie, and a newbie to the whole process of writing tests.

This is my controller:

```
angular
  .module('myModule', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.questionIndex = -1;
    $scope.text = "Hello world";
}]);
```

My view (index.html) is as follows:

```
<div id="text">{{ text }}</div>
```

This is my test, which is passing fine:

```
describe('Controller: myCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('myCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should have the initial question index set to -1', function () {
    expect(scope.questionIndex).toBe(-1);
  });

});
```

Now I want to write a test to check that the `text` element was actually rendered to the page.

How can I do this in Jasmine? Sorry, it's probably a stupid question but I can't figure it out from the documentation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'll give you two answers to your question:

**First:** Testing bindings in your view should probably be done in an end-to-end (E2E) test. And end to end test is used to make sure that the controllers, models and views are working together as expected, along with properly integrating your backend (if you have one).  This is where you would test that the given `div` has the expected text in it.  You can read all about that in the developer guide [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing).  The reason you use an E2E test for this is because the binding isn't truly a responsibility of your controller.  The controller handles/manipulates the model.  The model is then passed to the view, and it is the view's responsibility to then render the DOM elements using that model.  The only reliable way to test your DOM elements is through an E2E test.

**Second:** It can actually be done in a unit test, but the way to do it isn't exactly pretty.  You can do this by using angular's [`$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) service.  This service is what angular uses to parse through the DOM and turn all bindings/directives/etc into the end product.  Here's an example of how that would be done:

```
var scope, compile, elem;
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    compile = $compile;
    MainCtrl = $controller('myCtrl', {
       $scope: scope
    });
}));

it('should set the div content to "' + scope.text + '"', function(){
    var html = '<div id="text">{{ text }}</div>';
    elem = angular.element(html);  // turn html into an element object
    compile(elem)(scope); // compile the html
    scope.$digest();  // update the scope
    expect(elem.text()).toBe(scope.text);  //test to see if it was updated.
});
```

For more info on this second option, please see the detailed tutorial found [here](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/06/angular-js-unit-testing-directives.html). Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, in  elem = angular.element(html); what is elem?

Comment: I updated my response. I was missing the declaration for `elem`. Its just the `Element` object that is returned from the call to `angular.element()` which compiles the HTML string into an actual object.

Comment: +1 for _Testing bindings in your view should probably be done in an end-to-end (E2E) test_. I have found it too much trouble to try and test the controller and the view at the same time. I am now keeping the binding expressions in the view as simple as possible and testing the controller only.

Comment: Does this still work in 1.3 since you have to explicitly define the controller? How would we do that?

Comment: @Jackie I'm not sure what you mean by "explicity define the controller"... what change in 1.3 are you referring to? I believe all of the code above should work just fine in 1.3.  I believe the controller was "explicitly defined" when Richard wrote:

Comment: .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.questionIndex = -1;
    $scope.text = "Hello world";
}]);

Comment: I was referring to the window controller section here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Comment: Oh no. The above code will work the same for globally-declared init functions and for implicitly declared ones. So there's nothing different you have to do.

Comment: FWIW: I have done this for a time and jotted down two simple HTML aware tests as examples. https://github.com/LosManos/AngularHtmlTestTemplate